# AgGridReact headerCheckboxSelectionCurrentPageOnly Does Not Work on selecting all rows in the current page

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

My AgGridReact does not seem to follow the property ***headerCheckboxSelectionCurrentPageOnly*** .
My checkbox is in the header which works to select or unselect all records. But since I have a huge amount of data in the grid, we only want to implement selecting the current page of the ag grid.

Here's my sample code

```
     const autoGroupColumnDef = {
    headerCheckboxSelection: enableBulkAction,
    headerCheckboxSelectionCurrentPageOnly: true,
    cellRendererParams: {checkbox: enableBulkAction}
  }
```

Where *enableBulkAction* is boolean and turns to TRUE if the user wants to do a bulk update on a button click.

I also tried to put it in the header parameter in columnDef but no luck.

```
 { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', isDefault: true, checkboxSelection: enableBulkAction, headerCheckboxSelection: enableBulkAction, headerCheckboxSelectionCurrentPageOnly: true  },
```

let me know if you need more information.